# Getting Invalid Scope with new Permission pages_show_list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'd like to be able to access to the list of pages that the user manage, without using `manage_page`.

Since 2.5 (Facebook api version) they added `pages_show_list` allowing you just to see the list of pages. It's perfect for me, it's allowing me to just do a GraphRequest `/me/Accounts` without `manage_page`.

**PROBLEM:** 
I tried to add `pages_show_list` permission to the login button (with `setReadPermission()`)

But I'm getting a Invalid Scope on the app. I tried with setPublishPermission but got an Exception in java. They are not meant to be together.

Comment: Are you sure your app is using v2.5?

Comment: how am i supposed to update it, 2.5 is the version of the graph api, i updated the sdk to 4.7.0, still the same problem.

Comment: I would recommend trying this on our [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and/or fbrell.com and see if you can repro this on other platforms (i.e. to check if this is an isolated mobile SDK issue). If you can confirm that this is actually a bug then feel free to report it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

Comment: Invalid Scopes: pages_show_list. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: Getting the same problem here, maybe they haven't updated their end yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved after deleting facebook sdk from android studio and putting the new one again + deleting project and creating new one on the facebook dashboard.

On the facebook dashboard it shown that i was using the 2.4 Api before i unistalled everything.

Answer (score 10):

After searching trying for 2 long hours finally fond my mistake ....
Maybe this will help you too ...

Be sure to not to add "AccessToken" in the list of permissions that you are asking .

Eg. your permissions should **be like** -

```
List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
"user_birthday", "public_profile");
```

and **not like**

```
List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
"user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
```

Comment: I didn't add access token in my permissions array I asked only user_friends and user_gender but getting the same error.

Comment: If using the Swift library you can also derive this value from FacebookCore.Permission.name

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

Innitially i added `.userFriends, .userBirthday` in `readPermissions`

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ReadPermission.publicProfile, .email, .userFriends, .userBirthday], viewController : self)
```

I changed my code to

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ReadPermission.publicProfile, .email], viewController : self)
```

Now it's working.

Here any domain we need to to one thing, that is remove `.userFriends, .userBirthday` in `readPermissions`

Answer (score 0):

Do Not ask Permission for AccessToken

```
List< String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
            "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
```

remove "**AccessToken**"

```
  List< String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
            "user_birthday", "public_profile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add it in the Facebook developer console permissions requests section.